# How to use different text color and size for closed and opened dropdown list in Spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

I want to show the dropdown list items of the `Spinner` in a different color compared to selected item shown when the `Spinner` dropdown list is closed, how should I edit my spinner adapter to solve this problem?

```
public class MySpinner extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private String[] options;

    private String mCustomText = "";

    public MySpinner(Context context, String options[]) {
        super(context, R.layout.spinner_item, options);
        this.options = options;
    }

    public MySpinner(Context context, String options[], int resID) {
        super(context, resID);
        this.options = options;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        int specialItemIndex = options.length - 1;
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
    }
}
```

[image]

In other words I need simply that the text color and size of the item circled in red differ from the items in dropdown list circled in blue... actually using `R.layout.spinner_item` both have the same text size and color used in this layout

Comment: So, you want your selected item to change color and you want your Spinner title color to change to that color when the Spinner is closed?

Comment: Do you want the color to be always the same?

Comment: look at the picture, I need simply that the text color and size of the item circled in red differ from the items in dropdown list circled in blue... actually using `R.layout.spinner_item` both have the same text size and color

Comment: Do you have a `Spinner` View on your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can have your `Spinner` title text color set to blue (for example), while the `Spinner` items have the default color. Just apply it in `onItemSelected()` callback. Like this:

```
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long itemId) {
                    ((TextView)view).setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) { }
        });
```

Be sure that your `Spinner` item `View` is a `TextView`, so you can change the text color.